# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'match'):

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, typeerror, react-props

```
Product.find((x)=>x._id===props.params.match.id);

products: [
      {
        _id: '1',
        name: 'Nike Slim Shirt',
        category: 'Shirts',
        image: '/images/p1.jpg',
        price: 120,
        countInStock: 10,
        brand: 'Nike',
        rating: 4.5,
        numReviews: 10,
        description: 'high quality product',
      },
```

Comment: Please post a complete [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Because **Params** property is undefined.

Comment: how could i define it?

Comment: For express an opinion, you should give more details about your code base